# std::vector against std::vector with custom allocator

Tags: c++

Well I'm using my own allocator for a vector that has fast run-time requirements to avoid calling new/delete. The problem is now that code like this is not compiling:

```
std::vector<char> x(1000);
std::vector<char,myalloc<char>> y(1000);
x = y;
```

This obviously occurs because the implementation of the std::vector's allocator is compile-time and changes the type. But code like the above should be allocator-independent.

For POD I can do memcpy of course, but is there any other method? I'm really close to implementing my own vector that would use a custom allocator *dynamically*, specified at run time and get rid of std::vector.

Comment: Can you use assign? https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign

Comment: @jtbandes yes but this would require a big edit in the code.

Comment: `x.assign(y.begin(), y.end())` or (C++11)   `x.assign(std::begin(y), std::end(y))` should do it.   A vector's `operator=()` doesn't have overloads for that to work, regardless of what you think "should" be the case.   If you really want a type which works that way, create a simple `struct`/`class` type - templated if required - that contains a vector (with whatever element type and allocator you use) and ensure its `operator=()` works as required.

Comment: If I'm not mistaken you can use `std::pmr::vector` instead of just `std::vector` everywhere and everything should "just work".

Answer (score 3):

> But code like the above should be allocator-independent.

Assigning the elements should indeed be allocator-independent.  But the [copy assignment operator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/operator%3D) of `std::vector` does more than just assign elements — it also takes care of allocators.  So it should not be allocator-independent.

`std::vector` does provide an interface for assigning elements only: the [`assign`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/assign) member function.  It can be used like this:

```
x.assign(y.begin(), y.end());
```

Since C++17, [polymorphic allocators](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/polymorphic_allocator) allow allocator-aware containers to have type-erased allocator support, so you can consistently use `std::pmr::vector<char>`, but it has some problems you need to consider — overhead of type erasure, different allocator propagation semantics, different interface, etc.

Comment: Good concise answer. I just want to add `begin()` and `end()` can also be used right in the ctor like `std::vector<whatever> y(x.begin(), x.end());`

Comment: @nada Yeah. In fact, they can be used in any context where a range denoted by a pair of iterators is needed